# Error, Putpkt write failed

Tags: iphone

Hi everyone I am dispalying remote images in tableview cell.While i scrolled through the images,delete one of them and reloaded them ,my application exited showing this warning message.

```
 Ignoring packet error, continuing...
    gdb stack trace at 'putpkt: write failed':

0   gdb-arm-apple-darwin
```

0x0019026b remote_backtrace_self + 54

```
recent remote packets prior to 'putpkt: write failed':
```

The code for TableView Cell images is

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *celltype=@"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:celltype];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"] autorelease];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        //cell.textLabel.text=[[resultarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"Service"];

        /*UIImage *indicatorImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"indicator.png"];
         cell.accessoryView =
         [[[UIImageView alloc]
         initWithImage:indicatorImage]
         autorelease];*/
        /*NSThread *thread=[[NSThread alloc]initWithTarget:self selector:@selector() object:nil];
         [thread setStackSize:44];
         [thread start];*/

        cell.backgroundView=[[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cell.png"]]autorelease];
        // [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"]] autorelease];

        cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;



    }


    UIImageView *imageView= [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(19, 15, 75, 68)];
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;

         frameImagePath= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://XYZplayz.com/snapit/products/%@",[[productInfoArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"Image"]];

    [imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:frameImagePath]placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"no_image.png"]];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];
    [imageView release];
    imageView = nil;
    return cell;
}
```

And the method i call to reload the data in table after deleting is

```
   -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {

        spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
        spinner.center = self.view.center;
        [self.view addSubview:spinner];
        [spinner startAnimating];
        [[SnapItParsing sharedInstance]assignSender:self];
        [[SnapItParsing sharedInstance]startParsingForShowProducts:appDel.userIdString];

    }
```

Comment: can you show some source code that might have caused this error

Comment: That happened One time with me after updating the images in tableviewcell from the server.See the updated code,but i don't think this is happening due to this code,the code is fine.There is something else which i am forgetting

Comment: @sabby none of the code you posted looks incorrect.  The calls to the `[SnapItParsing sharedInstance]` object are the only things that look out of place.  What's going on with that object?

Comment: @Dave  SnapItParsing is a singelton class,which have my parsing methods.That works fine.

Comment: @sabby then how about then `UIImageView` category that defines `setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:`?

Comment: @Dave that a Class which help me to do the lazy image loading,That is the delegate method of the class.It takes care of the memory management ,freeing up images which are not in view.

Comment: @sabby so how about you post some more code?

Comment: Can you give me your email address so that ,i can send you the code,i don't think that giving you chunks of good would help me..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Whenever I get this error, restarting Xcode and my device resolves the error.

Comment: I have done the same thing dear,Problem was resolved,but thanks for your reply.......

Answer (score 4):

Had to power off the phone to get it to clear the issue. Once restarted and with a clean start of xcode then it finally worked.